# Proving a vector identity for $\text{div}(\mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{G})$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Proving $$\text{div}(\mathbf{F} \times  \mathbf{G}) = \mathbf{G} \cdot \text{curl}(\mathbf{F}) - \mathbf{F}\cdot \text{curl}(\mathbf{G}).$$
I calculated the left hand side but its not the same as the right hand side. The right hand side has the coefficient of 2 multiplied by each term

Here's the problem:
[image]

Comment: If you show your work, we can point out the mistake that you have done.Otherwise, you questions will probably be closed.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Just edited my post, there's an imgur link to my work.

Answer (score 1):

A more advanced approach, just for the sake of interest and future needs.

$$
\nabla \cdot (F\times G) = \sum_{i,j,k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\epsilon_{ijk} u_j v_k) = \sum_{i,j,k} \epsilon_{ijk}\left(G_k\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} + F_j\frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_i} \right),
$$

whereas
$$
(\nabla \times F)\cdot G - (\nabla\times G)\cdot F = \sum_{i,j,k}G_i\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j} - \sum_{i,j,k}F_i\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_j}.
$$

Now observe:

$$
\sum_{i,j,k}G_i\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j} = - \sum_{i,j,k}G_i\epsilon_{jik} \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j} = (-1)^2 \sum_{i,j,k}G_i\epsilon_{jki} \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j} \equiv \sum_{i,j,k}G_k\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i},
$$

where I have just reindexed in the last equality. Similarly:

$$
- \sum_{i,j,k}F_i\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_j} = (-1)^2 \sum_{i,j,k}F_i\epsilon_{jik} \frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_j} \equiv \sum_{i,j,k}F_j\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_i}.
$$

Hence:

$$
(\nabla \times F)\cdot G - (\nabla\times G)\cdot F = \sum_{i,j,k}F_j\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_i} + \sum_{i,j,k}G_k\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{i,j,k}\epsilon_{ijk}\left( G_k\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} + F_j\frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_i}\right) =$$
$$ \nabla \cdot (F\times G),
$$

such as we want.

Remember: in the first equation I have used the Leibniz rule to achive two terms. The second trick is a game with indices and properties of the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$.